# Want to rewrite php extension along with get parameter which does exist inside a folder not root

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example i have domain named as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) , I have a url http://www.example.com/demo/content.php?gt=1 , I wanted to rewrite like http://www.example.com/demo/index.php , Here demo is sub directory , I am not sure how to do it , I tried in htaccess but gives me internal server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your point add below code in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^demo([^/]+)/index.php$ /demo/content.php?gt=$1  [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks shantun, I want to know one more thing , this is for my subdirectory , if i want to remove .php extention for my root directory for example example.com/get-data.php?gt=1 to example.com/get-data/ and parameter should be recieved on get-data.php

Comment: add one more row : 

RewriteRule ^get-data/(.+) /get-data.php?gt=$1 [L]